# Error in FindIntegrationAnchors- Seurat package

Tags: scrnaseq

I am working on integrating a labelled single cell RNA seq cell atlas with an unlabelled one. I am wondering how do I determine the value of max.features when integrating two single cell RNA seq datasets?

Below is the code I am using:

```
epithelial = Read10X(data.dir="/projects/b1025/sdi0596/Covid19_Single_Cell_RNASeq_project/filtered_matrices_count/epithelial/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/",gene.column=1,cell.column=1)
habermann = Read10X(data.dir="/projects/b1025/sdi0596/Covid19_Single_Cell_RNASeq_project/filtered_matrices_count/Habermann_Single_Cell_Data/",gene.column=1,cell.column=1)

data.list=c(epithelial,habermann)

normalize and identify variable features for each dataset independently
ifnb.list <- lapply(X = data.list, FUN = function(x) {
x <- NormalizeData(x)
x <- FindVariableFeatures(x, selection.method = "vst", nfeatures = 2000)
})

Perform integration
immune.achors= FindIntegrationAnchors(object.list = ifnb.list,max.features = 200,verbose = TRUE)

Error in FindIntegrationAnchors(object.list = ifnb.list, max.features = 200, :
Max dimension too large: objects 1, 2 contain fewer than 30 cells.
Please specify a maximum dimensions that is less than the number of cells in any object (4).
```

Regarding the dimension of these objects, the epithelial one is 33538 x 49109 and the habermann is 33694 x 220213.
Any insights would be highly helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems with your code, first, when you do `Read10X()` it returns you a sparse matrix, and you need to put this into a `Seurat` object with meta data, before doing the integration.

So for example, i create some example data that is similar to your output from `Read10X()` :

library(Matrix)

```
epithelial = Matrix(matrix(rnbinom(100000,mu=200,size=1),ncol=50),sparse=TRUE)
rownames(epithelial) = paste0("gene",1:2000)
colnames(epithelial) = paste0("e",1:50)

habermann = epithelial + rnbinom(100000,mu=20,size=1)
colnames(habermann) = paste0("h",1:50)
```

Then convert to a seurat object:

```
data.list=c(epithelial = CreateSeuratObject(epithelial),
            habermann = CreateSeuratObject(habermann))
```

Then find variable features:

```
data.list <- lapply(data.list, FUN = function(x) {
x <- NormalizeData(x)
x <- FindVariableFeatures(x, selection.method = "vst", nfeatures = 2000)
})
```

Should look like this:

```
$epithelial
An object of class Seurat 
2000 features across 50 samples within 1 assay 
Active assay: RNA (2000 features, 2000 variable features)

$habermann
An object of class Seurat 
2000 features across 50 samples within 1 assay 
Active assay: RNA (2000 features, 2000 variable features)
```

Now perform integration, below I have to reduce `k.filter` because I have very little cells in this example. In your case, you can simply use the default settings.

```
features <- SelectIntegrationFeatures(object.list = data.list)
anchors= FindIntegrationAnchors( data.list,max.features = 200,
k.filter=50,k.anchor = 3,verbose = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some of your samples have too few cells, so it is recommended to check the data and remove samples with low cell counts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).